# Bash Script to Delete using find

Tags: bash, shell, duplicates

How to delete duplicate files using this find command:

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.xml" \) -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -rg | sed -r 's/[^ ]* //' | awk '{w=$0; sub(".*/", "", w); sub("_[0-9_][0-9_]*.*", "", w);} !a[w]++'
```

This command is to fetch unique filenames but how to make it to delete duplicate filenames. pls assist.

Answer (score 0):

The below script can be used to find and remove the duplicate file. It will keep only one copy from the duplicate file list.

find . -type f ( -iname "*.xml" ) > /tmp/fileList.txt;
dupFileList=$(cat /tmp/fileList.txt | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{if($1>1) print $2}' | tr '\n' ' '); 
for files in $dupFileList; 
do
    cat /tmp/fileList.txt | grep $files | awk 'NR>1' | xargs rm -f; 
done